# How can I create a dynamic list of routes from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I have a JSON file containing information for a tile based navigation app which uses the Router. Each tile could be a link directly to an external application, or it could contain subtiles which are displayed when the tile is clicked. Each of these could have their own subtiles, and so on. The JSON will eventually be delivered by an OData service so the app needs to dynamically create the navigation as it may change.

How can I implement the Router to have the URL looking like `#tile1/tile1-1/tile1-1-3` which would indicate the user clicked on the first tile, which went to a screen where they clicked on the first tile there, followed by another screen on which they clicked the third tile? That route would, when coming from a bookmark, load the screen with subtiles from the tile1-1-3 node from the JSON.

The names 'tile1-1-3' etc are only to help visualise the position of the tile for this example. In the real version the names won't indicate the position in the tree, they will be more like `#MyApps/MyApprovalApps`.

I have a recursive function which crawls through every node and generates an individual route, but I'm unsure how to add the dynamic pattern like `{tile}/{subtile}/{subtile}` and also the parent route which I think will be needed to navigate between the levels properly.

I have a `Home.view.xml` which displays the top level tiles, and a `Page1.view.xml` for the rest of the levels of subtiles. Is this correct? How can I create the views dynamically if not?

Hopefully my goal is clear, I can elaborate more if needed.

Recursive function which creates the routes:

```
createRoutes: function(aData, oRouter){
  for(var i=0; i<aData.length; i++){
    oRouter.addRoute({name: aData[i].id,
                      pattern: aData[i].title,
                      view: "Page1"}); //parent?

    if(aData[i].subtiles.length > 0){ // has subtiles        
      this.createRoutes(aData[i].subtiles, oRouter);
    }
  }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "TilesCollection" : [
    {
      "id"     : "tile1",
      "title"  : "tile1",
      "target" : "#",
      "subtiles" : [
        {
          "id"     : "tile1-1",
          "title"  : "tile1--1",
          "target" : "#",
          "subtiles" : []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id"     : "tile2",
      "title"  : "tile2",
      "target" : "#",
      "subtiles" : [
        {
          "id"     : "tile2-1",
          "title"  : "tile2--1",
          "target" : "#",
          "subtiles" : []
        },
        {
          "id"     : "tile2-2",
          "title"  : "tile2--2",
          "target" : "#",
          "subtiles" : []
        },
        {
          "id"     : "tile2-3",
          "title"  : "tile2--3",
          "target" : "#",
          "subtiles" : [
            {
              "id"     : "tile2-3-1",
              "title"  : "tile2--3--1",
              "target" : "#",
              "subtiles" : []
            },
            {
              "id"     : "tile2-3-2",
              "title"  : "tile2--3--2",
              "target" : "#",
              "subtiles" : []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id"     : "tile3",
      "title"  : "tile3",
      "target" : "#",
      "subtiles" : []
    },
    {
      "id"     : "tile4",
      "title"  : "tile4",
      "target" : "#",
      "subtiles" : [
        {
          "id"     : "tile4-1",
          "title"  : "tile4--1",
          "target" : "#",
          "subtiles" : []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
createRoutes: function(aData, oRouter, sParentPattern, iViewLevel) {
  iViewLevel = iViewLevel || 0;

  for (var i=0; i<aData.length; i++) {
    var sPattern = sParentPattern ? sParentPattern +"/"+ aData[i].title : aData[i].title;

    oRouter.addRoute({
      name: aData[i].id,
      pattern: sPattern,
      view: "Page1",
      viewLevel : iViewLevel
    });

    if (aData[i].subtiles.length > 0) {        
      this.createRoutes(aData[i].subtiles, oRouter, sPattern, iViewLevel+1);
    }
  }
}
```

In this example you just use the pattern to build the parent-child relationship just as you suggested.

Comment: I took your logic and applied it to my own version which also set the parent route, and it works great. Now the routes are set only where it has subtiles (no point setting a route for a tile that has no subtiles itself), and if they are subtiles, the parent route is set, along with the proper pattern provided by your code. Thanks very much. Still a bit of work to get this app functional, but I've really enjoyed the problem solving on this one!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're asking how can you represent th clicking route as a string, whcih you can pass as prt of a URL ?

Referring to the tile IDs...

You could pass the text in as a JS array of objects I guess (ie include this JSON as part of the URL) :

a.b.com/xyz?route=[{"tile1-1",{"tile1-1"}},{"tile2",{"tile2-3"}}]

meaning they clicked tile1 -> tile1-1 -> tile2 -> tile2-3

Alternatively if the Ids are potentially secure or something, you could pass it by index no. as it's an aray :
a.b.com/xyz?route=[{0,{0}},{0,{2}}]

Then eval the passed string to turn it directly into Javascript object.
Or if you're concerned about people hacking, write a routine to interpret it.

(same clicking as above) - this relies on the tile arrangement  never changing though.

Comment: I actually want to use the Router mechanism of UI5 to handle the forming of the URLs, which will also tell the View which tiles to display, and can also navigate back up the chain to higher level tiles.

Comment: I think you need to explain the context more - I don't know what UI5 is I'm afraid. Or perhaps provide a JSFiddle if possible.